# JFileChooser - select audio (.wav) - Java

Tags: java, wav, jfilechooser

I have a problem with selecting a wav. near is code:

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
                            "mp3 & wav Images", "wav", "mp3");
chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(getParent());
if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        System.out.println("You chose to open this file: " + chooser.getSelectedFile().getName());
}

InputStream in = new FileInputStream(chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());  
AudioStream as = new AudioStream(in);  
AudioPlayer.player.start(as);
```

I got error in eclipse for AudioStream and AudioPlayer, i use JDK 7. How to solve the problem?

Comment: Could you please post your error stacktrace for analysis!

Comment: What kind of error are you talking about? Runtime error? Compile error? ...

Comment: ok i changed Build Path bacuse there was old JDK

Answer (score 1):

This SSCCE works for me. I'm running jdk 1.7.0_45 on linux. I tested it with the file

`/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/gallery/sounds/train.wav`

Main.java

```
import sun.audio.AudioPlayer;
import sun.audio.AudioStream;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

/**
 * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20639187/jfilechooser-select-audio-wav-java
 */
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("mp3 & wav Images", "wav", "mp3"));
        if (chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
            AudioStream as = new AudioStream(in);
            AudioPlayer.player.start(as);
        }
        // Move the code that was here, to play the file, inside the if statement so the
        // application doesn't crash if the user doesn't select a file to play.
    }
}
```

You can test it from the command line with the following:

```
javac Main.java
java Main
```

In the code that you posted, you would have gotten a runtime error if you didn't select a file from the JFileChooser because you're trying to access the selected file even if the user doesn't choose one.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following snippet, that worked for me several times:

```
...
URL url = ClassLoader.getResource(chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);
Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
clip.open(ais);
...
```

also discussed in [How to cast from InputStream to AudioInputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10591852/how-to-cast-from-inputstream-to-audioinputstream)

btw: your code works fine on my machine...